# How to make an introductory course on Statistics interesting

Tags: undergraduate-education, statistics

I am going to teach this probability and statistics course in a couple of weeks. The probability part can be made very interesting, in my opinion, easily. But I am a little worried that I might make the statistics part a boring collection of information and algorithmic manipulations. So my question is, how do I make the statistics part of the course interesting?

The syllabus for the stat part is roughly the contents of this [book](https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/459).

Comment: That's a lot of topics to cover! There may not be room, but a project where the students apply the statistics to data of interest to them, can generate considerable enthusiasm.

Comment: Who are the intended students?  High school students?  Undergraduates?

Comment: First year undergraduates.

Comment: In my opinion, it can't be done.

Comment: I don’t know who your clientele is, but my students, half of which are business-degree candidates, seem more excited by the statistics part of the course than the probability. It could have to do with the quasi-real scenarios for the problems and emphasis on practical applications. And the use of computation to avoid drudgery.

Comment: I've always liked **How to Lie With Statistics**. It was originally published in 1954 but was reissued in 1993.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding a bit on my comment, there is (1) a new textbook available for
project-based intro stats, (2) an online syllabus describing a course based
on community projects, and (3) an academic paper concluding that
"the project-based course ... provides a promising model for getting students hooked on the power and excitement of applied statistics."

- (1) Chelsea Myers. *Project-Based R Companion to Introductory Statistics*.
  [Routledge link](https://www.routledge.com/Project-Based-R-Companion-to-Introductory-Statistics/Myers/p/book/9780367262082).
- (2) Cindy Kaus, *Introductory Statistics with Community-Based Projects*.
  [Metropolitan link](https://ncsce.net/introductory-statistics-with-community-based-projects/).
- (3) Dierker, Lisa, Jane Robertson Evia, Karen Singer-Freeman, Kristin Woods, Janet Zupkus, Alan Arnholt, Elizabeth G. Moliski, Natalie Delia Deckard, Kristel Gallagher, and Jennifer Rose. "Project-based learning in introductory statistics: Comparing course experiences and predicting positive outcomes for students from diverse educational settings." *International Journal of Educational Technology and Learning* 3, no. 2 (2018): 52-64.
  [Journal link](http://scipg.com/index.php/101/article/view/26).

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty normal to have a lot of ground to cover.  Even with the more friendly books, it still ends up being a lot of concepts and formulas.  Given this, I think you sort of have to make your peace with the idea that kids will not master everything, especially in the long term. I probably wouldn't try some fundamental change to improve things since it may make things worse (like adding a big project or the like).  Just engage with the kids, be animated and sort of cheerlead through the thing.  Maybe tell a sea story or two.

Whereas I have an iconic recall of the quadratic formula, I don't think I've ever used a chi test in a class or business/engineering situation.  And I don't remember the formula.  Or what is different about it versus a t test.  But at least I sorta "heard of it".

In terms of basic lasting concepts, I think they should have lasting knowledge that normal distribution is a "bell curve" and is a decent guess when you have no clue.  Along with the very basic concepts of confidence intervals (not every tricky caveat or logic issue but just the idea of 90% CI).

After that, just the info that there are a lot of concepts, formulas, and things can be tricky.  So if someone quotes a statistic know that it may have issues.  And if you are working on something statistical, bring in a professional/watch out for errors.  [But again, I know "rigor people" hate this, but I think you have to set the bar lower at "exposure" rather than "mastery".  Pound smart, not penny foolish.]

Comment: I rarely think "exposure" is useful to anyone.  If there are too many topics to actually understand or retain anything, remove topics until you have a course which can be comprehended.

Comment: You've pretty much described the "Fundamentals of Statistics & Probability" course that I underwent as a freshman. I detest and despise the procedural-over-conceptual philosophy underpinning the design and delivery of most Statistics courses, which are such missed opportunities to actually inculcate statistical literacy.

Comment: Not sure how a mile wide and an inch deep is pound smart.